# How to achieve android Recyclerview kind of functionality in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Let say i have 100 data in json object, Some data contain Video url, some contains Audio URL, Some data contains Extra table columns with Image Url.

In android i have Recycler View where i will create different fragments UI and based on the condition i'll load the UI and data and display on the listview.

But in nativescript i found only radist view which takes only similar type of data and display the list.

How to Achieve android's RecyclerView kind of functionality in Nativescript.

(Kindly anyone edit my question in a more generic way)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/list-view) or [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radlistview), both support configuring various templates and assign one to each list item based on conditions.

RadListView has more advanced features / support for various layouts out of the box, it uses RecyclerView on Android, where ListView uses `android.widget.ListView`.

Comment: can you give any example links for reference

Comment: Here is a direct link to page if you are still not able to find it - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/RadListView/overview

Comment: sorry I'm still not getting the concept of different layouts there. it is just 3 layouts staggered, list, grid. i know how to use it. but i need to load different ui on each list element like in recyclerview of android. that part i'm not getting.

Comment: That part is called using multiple templates. Just read the documentation with patience, you have all the examples.